# Using virt-install within a larger script

Tags: scripting, kvm, libvirt

I'm trying to use `virt-install` within a larger script and running into a problem. Once a new guest is installed via kickstart, I need to run some commands on the new VM. Right now, I'm simply adding those commands within a larger BASH script after the `virt-install` command.

The problem is that, no matter whether I specify 'shutdown' or 'halt' or another option in the kickstart file, it doesn't disconnect from the VM console. I have to manually intervene to disconnect the console and have it return to the script running on the host, which is undesirable. I've tried adding the `--noautoconsole` flag to keep the console from attaching but the problem there is that the script then continues on the host before the installation is complete.

Is there a way to run the `virt-install` command and either detach from the console at the end and return to the host machine's console? If not, is there a way to use the `--noautoconsole` flag such that my script doesn't continue prior to the guest being fully installed?

Thank you!